# Ability to use Methods from 1 class in another in Java

Tags: java, class, methods

Assume you have a class A. A creates an instance of Class B, which in turn creates an Instance of class C.

Class A is a main method, and its sole job is to create an instance of Class B.
Class B is a simulator, containing a few methods that run the program for X "steps".
Class C has a GUI, with a single button and a grid that can update.It contains all the methods to do this.

For the button in Class C to function, it must use a method in class B, which in turn uses another method in class C.

Is it possible for C to use a method from B, without creating ANOTHER instance of B within C?

The code in C when the button is clicked,

```
[snip]
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSteps; i++){
    B.simulateOneStep(); 
}
[snip]
```

this runs the following code in B,

```
public void simulateOneStep()
{
    step++;

    List<Animal> newAnimals = new ArrayList<Animal>();        
    for(Iterator<Animal> it = animals.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        Animal animal = it.next();
        animal.act(newAnimals);
        if(! animal.isAlive()) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }

    animals.addAll(newAnimals);

    C.showStatus(step, field);
}
```

From testing I have conducted, the simulateOneStep() method runs UNTIL the line C.showStatus(), after which it does not run this line until the last iteration of the initial for loop (i.e. for 10 steps, you should see 10 different displays on the grid.The program runs all 10 steps properly,however it only displays the final one).

Is it possible to run methods this way? I have attempted adding showStatus() into the for loop in the Class C method but this made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to do this is for `C` to have a reference to its "parent" `B` object.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the model (in this case the simulation), should ideally be UI agnostic (i.e. it should have intimate knowledge of the UI, like implementation details or layout specifics). Without getting into full-blown MVC, one way to achieve this is by way of the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood what you are asking, but let's give it a shot anyway.

Are you saying you want to call C.showStatus(step, field); 10 times?

if so I think you should just include it in the for loop right after the if statement.

Comment: What it should do is for each step, update the grid, then show the grid to the user. So for X steps, it will update,re-draw,show, then update,re-draw,show etc. I've tried adding it in the for loop but it does not have any effect.

Comment: So it is only showing the last Grid either ways? How is the grid the grid being displayed? is it a new grid each time? or are you like Drawing over the same form? What I am suggesting is try to pause the process right after every grid update (just for debugging pruposes)

Answer (score 0):

I see four options.
First, as @louis-wasserman said, pass a reference to the parent, so C's constructor would look something like:

```
private B sim;
public C(B sim){
    this.sim = sim;
}
```

B would create it with:

```
C gui = new C(this);
```

and when the button is pressed, C would call:

```
sim.simulateOneStep();
```

Second (my least favorite) make everything in B static -- all its methods and variables.  Then C can just refer to it directly with:

```
B.simulateOneStep();
```

If you go that way, you may as well give B a main method and leave A out of it.

Third, you could have A managing the creation of simulators and guis, so that C would look the same as in the first solution, but A would create an instance of each within main thusly:

```
B sim = new B();
C gui = new C(sim);
sim.init();
C.begin();
```

Fourth, you could make the instance of B a public static property of A, which C could then refer to.

Of all of these, I like options one and three best.